# Graph API - Access room calendar using a delegate

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm looking into possible approach to access a room's calendar using a delegated account. I have registered a confidential client application on AAD, which seems to work fine but I'm considering to use a specific account(provided it has all the necessary permissions) to do this on behalf of any room resource. So for e.g. when a request from abc@test.com (which is a room mailbox) comes, xyz@test.com(delegated account) retreives abc's calendar events and returns to the application. 
Which OAuth2.0 grant flow is applicable can I use in this case? My application is a desktop based app which can talk to a WCF services in order to retrieve room's calendar.

Comment: Do you have a chance to look into my answer? Any updates?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you could do that.

You need to give the Full Access mailbox delegation of room mailbox to delegated account in Exchange Admin Center.

Follow [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) to use **auth code flow** to get the access token.

Then just use `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{room mailbox}/calendar` to get the room calendar.

The required permissions should be `Calendars.Read`, `Calendars.Read.Shared`.